# How to display users by group using mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason I feel this is a very easy task but I just can't get my head around it. I have two tables. Table A is list of companies called company and Table B is a list of users called users. The user table has a filed called 'access' which stores the ids of all the companies that a user is allowed to see.

companies

```
id  name    
--  ----
1   coca cola
2   samsung
3   apple
4   microsoft
```

users

```
id  access    name    
--  ------    ----
1   1,3,4     brain owen
2   2,3       janet smith
2   1,2,4     peter pete
2   2,3,4     jane dow
```

My problem is how do I display the list of users who have access to a particular company? eg coca cola. Thank you.

Comment: Yet again - storing multiple values in one field via separator violates relation DB principles and causes troubles (you're in the middle of one of them). Normalize your DB.

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend removing the `access` column on table `users` and create another table called `user_access`. In there you can store the company id and the user id. If you continue on the road you're on, you're destined for troubles!

Comment: to expand on above, ditch the access columb, and create a user_company table to link them

Comment: thanx guys and I totally agree with you. But I had to result to this method because the companies where selected through a multiple select form. If I create another table user_access, this will create another problem ie how to add data from a multiple select input form to the user_access table.

Answer (score 1):

```
id  name    
--  ----
1   coca cola
2   samsung
3   apple
4   microsoft

userId  companyId
------  ---------
1       1
1       3
1       4
2       2
2       3

id  name    
--  ----
1   brain owen
2   janet smith
```

Two users can't have the same ID...

Comment: And then, `SELECT name FROM users,havingAccess WHERE havingAcces.userId=users.id AND havingAcces.companyId=3`.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will give you the user name of coca cola

```
select name from users where access in(1)
```

Comment: actually it would be 1 in name... i.e name LIKE '%1%'